# Temperature differences between CPU & GPU

Tags: temperature, gpu, cpu

So recently I was interested in CPU and GPU temperatures and did some work displaying the temperatures in real time on a page and also recording the temperatures on a graph using `rrdtool` (which is very awesome). I've also been logging the temperatures for a while now.

[image]

Pop quiz: Can you see where I added the active cooling?

But then I got to wondering if the one temperature affected the other. Makes sense. So I did a (very brief) Google search to find out which chip was the CPU and which the GPU.

[image]

Ok, so, wait, they're on the same chip.... So why Am I getting (slightly) different temperatures?
[image]

And are there really 2 separate temperature sensors on the one chip?

Here's an "close up" of the last 15 minutes (5 minute heartbeat)
[image]

Comment: Your graph is on a reeeeeally looooong timescale. Would it be possible to choose one of the sections where you've noticed a significant difference and show a graph of, say, 10 minutes worth of activity, or low enough that single data points can be identified? It's hard to say just from the graph what the specific differences are between the two data sets.

Comment: What commands you are using to read the temperature?  As fas as I am aware there is only one sensor.

Comment: I'll build up shorter time graph tomorrow, but the commands are:

`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`

&

`/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp`

Comment: I believe they are two different interfaces to the same sensor.

Comment: I've added that last graph as requested @goobering

Comment: Thanks @joan, it may be, but I'm not convinced yet. Why are there so many changes between the 2 readings?

Answer (score 3):

I just took 5000 samples as follows.

```
time for ((i=0;i<5000;i++)); \
   do \
      cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp; \
      /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp; \
   done >temp
```

The 5000 samples were collected in about 150 seconds, or about 33 per second.

```
real    2m26.588s
user    0m29.090s
sys     0m47.510s
```

---

[image: thermal zone]

thermal zone

---

[image: vcgencmd]

vcgencmd

---

They appear to be the same sensor.

---

As a second experiment I used this script suggested by Jim

```
#!/bin/bash

T1="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"
T2="/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"

R1a=$($T1)
R2a=$($T2)
R1b=$($T1)
R2b=$($T2)
R1c=$($T1)
R2c=$($T2)
R1d=$($T1)
R2d=$($T2)

echo ${R1a:0:2}.${R1a:2:1} ${R2a:5:4} ${R1b:0:2}.${R1b:2:1} ${R2b:5:4} ${R1c:0:2}.${R1c:2:1} ${R2c:5:4} ${R1d:0:2}.${R1d:2:1} ${R2d:5:4}
```

It was run with

```
for ((i=0;i<100;i++)); do ./1.sh; sleep 0.1; done
```

A fragment of output

```
37.9 39.0 39.0 39.0 38.4 39.0 38.4 38.5
38.4 39.0 38.4 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0 38.5
39.0 39.0 38.4 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0
38.4 39.0 39.0 38.5 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0
38.4 38.5 39.0 38.5 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0
38.4 38.5 38.4 38.5 39.0 39.0 39.0 39.0
```

Each line has readings from command 1 and command 2 repeated four times, e.g.

C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2 C1 C2

You should be able to see how variable successive readings may be.

Comment: Nicely done! There are a few outliers here and there, but I'd have thought that could be put down to timing issues rather than physically distinct sensors on the SOC. The 49.8/9 reading in the upper right corner would appear to strongly support only one sensor.

Comment: Actually that's not an outlier.  I use gnuplot and that's where it puts its key.  You can get consecutive readings which differ by a degree even at 33 per second.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Try this though:
Create a new file (I called mine 1.sh) with the following content:  
`#!/bin/bash`  
`TEMPERATURE="cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp"`  
`TEMPERATURE="echo -n ${TEMPERATURE:0:2};echo -n .; echo   
${TEMPERATURE:2:1}"`  
`TEMPERATURE2="/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp"`  
`TEMPERATURE2="echo -n ${TEMPERATURE2:5:4}"`  
`echo $TEMPERATURE`  
`echo $TEMPERATURE2`
Then `chmod`it to 755 to make it executable. Then run:  
`watch -n.01 1.sh` to run the script every .1 seconds
(sorry, tried to format it nicely, but i couldn't get the line-breaks working)

Comment: @Jim Shall do, may be this afternoon though.

Comment: @joan Cool, let me know if you want me to put that script up somewhere, I could use jsfiddle or something I guess.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what it is that I'm reading [here](http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-rpi-kernel/2015-October/002404.html), but it suggests that the Pi has a single (ST-Ericsson DB8500?) thermal sensor on the chip.

Comment: That seems to be the code which uses the Video Core mailbox interface to do the `vcgencmd measure_temp` and create the `/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp` alias.  So yes, they are the same thing.

Comment: @joan - That's a bit over my head. So what's the difference? Other than one being easier to read? Is running one more expensive than the other? Is there a delay on the /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp as it's a file that's being written to the whole time? (I'm trying to figure out why there are different readings for the 2 methods. - is one more accurate?)

Comment: @Jim The /sys interface appears to call the vc (video core) mailbox interface to read the same temperature.  Using the video core measure_temp function is the most direct.  If you look at consecutive readings you can see a lot of jitter on occasion.